# How can I set up Zk Sessions in a controller class extending SelectorComposer

Tags: java, zk

i can use session with controller class extends GenericForwardComposer but with controller class extending SelectorComposer is mark as an error

am using netbean with zkoss platform

Here is my ctrl:

```
package com.ctrl;


import com.impl.ChartImpl;
import com.koneksi.DaoFactory;
import org.zkoss.chart.Charts;
import org.zkoss.chart.Legend;
import org.zkoss.chart.PlotLine;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Session;
import org.zkoss.chart.model.ChartsModel;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.SelectorComposer;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.GenericForwardComposer;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.annotation.Wire;
import org.zkoss.zul.Window;

  public class LineBasicComposerCtrl extends GenericForwardComposer   {
// i need to use SelectorComposer<Window> for zkchart
//public class LineBasicComposerCtrl extends SelectorComposer<Window> {
  
    @Wire
    Charts chart;

    public void doAfterCompose(Window comp) throws Exception {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
//here is the error if i used SelectorComposer<Window>
        DaoFactory daofactory = (DaoFactory) session.getAttribute("daofactory");  
//here is the error if i used SelectorComposer<Window>
        
        chart.setModel((ChartsModel) ChartImpl.getCategoryModel(daofactory));    
        chart.getTitle().setX(-20);
        chart.getSubtitle().setX(-20);
        chart.getYAxis().setTitle("Temperature (°C)");
        PlotLine plotLine = new PlotLine();
        plotLine.setValue(0);
        plotLine.setWidth(1);
        plotLine.setColor("#808080");
        chart.getYAxis().addPlotLine(plotLine);
        chart.getTooltip().setValueSuffix("°C");
        Legend legend = chart.getLegend();
        legend.setLayout("vertical");
        legend.setAlign("right");
        legend.setVerticalAlign("middle");
        legend.setBorderWidth(0);
    }
}
```

fell free to ask more if you need something
thx alot for help

Answer (score 0):

Most likely scenario would be a class mismatch.
You mentioned that you are using a `SelectorComposer<Window>`.
That would only work if your declaration is on a Window component like (in zul file):

```
<zk>
    <window apply="foo.bar.MyComposer">
    ...
    </window>
</zk>
```

If your composer is applied to anything else (like a div component), then you will receive some sort of failed to cast exception.
For example, if you have something like:

```
<zk>
    <div apply="foo.bar.MyComposer">
    ...
    </div>
</zk>
```

If that's the case, you can try using a different type instead of Window for the `SelectorComposer<Type>` to match your host component. If you want something generic, you can use the org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component Interface.

```
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component;
...
MyComposer extends SelectorComposer<Component>
```

You should have an error message somewhere with a stacktrace. Most likely in your java console, but could be in your container's logs.
Please try to find that, and add it to the thread, as this will likely show the actual cause of the issue (in case I'm not quite right on the issue :D )

Edit: formatting